# Dual Monitor Configuration Keeps Changing Automatically

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have a Dell Vostro 3350 running Ubuntu 17.10 and Windows 10. The graphics cards I have are:

```
Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Seymour [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series] (rev ff)
```

When I boot into Ubuntu and connect my laptop to the second screen the display configuration keeps changing by itself. I have changed my HDMI cable and the second display but it still occurs. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Could you elaborate? ie desktop shortcuts move from one screen to the other, or left/right placement switches, etc.

Comment: The display layout changes from join screens to single screen to mirrored screens all by itself. And it repeats until I take out the HDMI cable from the laptop

Comment: I presume you want your laptop screen to be your primary screen containing your launcher (side bar tray) and desktop shortcut icons? Do you want your secondary screen to be "mirrored desktop" or "extended desktop"? Are you using Gnome desktop or Unity desktop environment?

Comment: How can I know the desktop environment I am using? I want to have a joined display setup. So that I can have different Windows working on the different screens

Comment: Your current desktop environment can be shown with `echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP`

Comment: I checked and it's Ubuntu GNOME

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, with nVidia card turned off (using Intel integrated GPU instead) and Unity desktop not GNOME desktop. Here is what I've found: 1) Turn on HDMI monitor before turning on or resuming Laptop. 2) Power off or suspend Laptop first, then turn off HDMI monitor. Otherwise my icons can get scrambled up. I've upvoted your question to bring more attention to it. Hopefully someone on your environment provides a better answer.

Comment: The problem is still persistent. I am forced to use Windows 10 even though I like Ubuntu. Please I need a fix

Comment: I have the same problem. I wonder if anyone else is using a Phillips monitor.